cloud functions: 'event.data' is possibly 'undefined'
I have been trying to write cloud functions(for firebase) for my project and I am stuck at writing cloud function syntax in typescript. I have watched a couple videos related to cloud functions at SQL-like joins in cloud firestore and cloud functions for firebase tutorial, they suggest typescript over javascript but I haven't seen syntax on Cloud Firestore triggers in typescript.
This is partial code snippet from document in javascript and I used it in node.ts file and I got this error message: 'event.data' is possibly 'undefined'
export const onUserUpdated = onDocumentUpdated(
"users/{userUid}",
async (event) => {

const newValue = event.data.after.data(); // <- error occurs with message when trying to deploy cloud function in typescript: 'event.data' is possibly 'undefined'.

// access a particular field as you would any JS property
const newType = newValue.type;

// Get an object with the previous document values
const previousValues = event.data.before.data(); // <- error occurs with message when trying to deploy cloud function in typescript: 'event.data' is possibly 'undefined'.
const previousType = previousValues.type;

if (newType !== previousType) {
  // logic part
}

return null;

}
);

I will appreciate it if you could help me writing equivalent typescript code for that javascript code snippet.

Did you try adding a ! to indicate that event.data is not undefined? So: event.data!.after.data()

Please edit the question to show the entire function you've written, stripped down to the minimum that causes this error.  The issue is a matter of data typing, not syntax, and we need to see the context for where this error happens (not just the one line).

it works! thank you for your help. I can mark it as answer if you post it as answer.

Solution by Frank van Puffelen:
event.data!.after.data()

